# Break out of a loop when signal handler returns

Tags: php, loops, signals, break

Is it possible to break out of a loop when interrupted by a signal? When I run the following code, if I send SIGINT during the first iteration of the loop, the signal handler is called, but then I'm dropped back into the loop. I'd like to handle the signal and then skip the rest of the loop (without exiting the script).

```
<?php
  declare(ticks = 1);

  function sig_handler($signo) {
    switch($signo) {
      case SIGINT:
        echo 'SIGINT' . PHP_EOL;
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'sig_handler');

  $vars = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
  foreach ($vars as $var) {
    echo $var . PHP_EOL;
    sleep(3);
  }

  // Do other stuff
?>
```

Output (ctrl+C during each sleep):

```
$ php foreach_test.php
foo
SIGINT
bar
SIGINT
baz
SIGINT
```

Comment: A very hackish solution: set a global variable in the signal handler and check its value in each loop iteration; if the variable is set, break out of the loop. This makes me wonder if I should even be using signals in this way, though.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, your "break" statement breaks the "switch", not the loop. Instead say something like:

```
if ($signo == SIGINT){
    echo 'SIGINT' . PHP_EOL;
    break;
}
```